# Python loop through a list how does it work?

Tags: python, list

I have tried to find an answer and sorry I can not seem to find one. in the following code:

```
friends = ['Bob','Luke','Ian', 'Frank']
for friend in friends:
    print (friend)
```

How does Python know what friend is, it is not defined, all we have told python is that we have a variable (in this case a list of items) called friends.

I am trying to work it out in my head before trying to explain it to students. Thanks for any help

Comment: "[friend] is not defined": Yes, you define it right there in the `for` statement :)

Comment: In java if u type anything in between " " it is taken as STRING like wise in python if u type type between [] it is taken as list and between {} it is taken as tuples it is done in their compilation code to take it that was to reduce the burden on the user side

Answer (score 6):

```
for friend in friends:
    print(friend)
```

is shorthand for

```
it = iter(friends)
while True:
    try:
        friend = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    print(friend)
```

Answer (score 4):

That's how `for` statement is implemented in Python. From the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

> The expression list is evaluated once; it should yield an iterable object. An iterator is created for the result of the expression_list. The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator, in the order of ascending indices. Each item in turn is assigned to the target list using the standard rules for assignments, and then the suite is executed.

So `friend` is not undefined, that's got defined by the `for` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Along side the other answers that explain nicety , and this fact that python assign the elements in list to name `friend` in each iteration  , you can use [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) module to see in detail :

```
>>> def fun():
    ...    friends = ['Bob','Luke','Ian', 'Frank']
    ...    for friend in friends:
    ...       print friend
    ... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(fun)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Bob')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('Luke')
              6 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Ian')
              9 LOAD_CONST               4 ('Frank')
             12 BUILD_LIST               4
             15 STORE_FAST               0 (friends)

  3          18 SETUP_LOOP              19 (to 40)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (friends)
             24 GET_ITER            
        >>   25 FOR_ITER                11 (to 39)
             28 STORE_FAST               1 (friend)

  4          31 LOAD_FAST                1 (friend)
             34 PRINT_ITEM          
             35 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             36 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           25
        >>   39 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   40 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             43 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see on following line, python began to assignment the `friend`  and after each iteration it assigned again :

```
15 STORE_FAST               0 (friends)
```

> The dis module supports the analysis of CPython bytecode by disassembling it. The CPython bytecode which this module takes as an input is defined in the file Include/opcode.h and used by the compiler and the interpreter

Answer (score 0):

`friend` is bound in the for statement. At each iteration of the loop, the next element of the iterable gets bound to it. The iterable is `friends` in your case.

The for syntax:

```
for element in iterable:
    pass
```

loops over `iterable`, binding each element to `element`.